# Loop through set of items forwards and backwards with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, loops, animation, settimeout

This one is breaking my head!

I have a list of items:

```
var prev = 'sally.charlie.ted';
var next = 'tina.heather.david';
```

And then I want to loop through them forwards and backwards with each one a 1 second delay:

```
animate(prev, function () {
    animate(next, function () {
        console.log('done');
    }, false);
}, true);
```

But now i'm confusing myself. maybe these is a better way to do thi?

```
function animate(url, callback, reverse, index, length) {
    var items = url.split('.'),
        total = items.length - 1;
    if (typeof index === 'undefined') { index = reverse ? items.length - 1 : 0; }
    if (typeof length === 'undefined') { length = reverse ? url.length + items[index].length + 1 : 0; }
    if (index > total || index < 0) {
        callback();
    } else {
        if (reverse === true) {
            length -= items[index].length + (items.length - index);
        } else {
            length += items[index].length + index;
        }
        console.log(url.length, total, length, items[index], url.slice(0, length));
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            animate(url, callback, reverse, reverse ? index - 1 : index + 1, length);
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

I want to get the correct full path for each item, either forwards or backwards. My desired output backwards would be:

```
ted = sally.charlie.ted
charlie = sally.charlie
sally = sally
```

And then forwards:

```
tina = tina
heather = tina.heather
david = tina.heather.david
```

Here is a working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/kmturley/oco5uxrn/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed a little bit your code.

Try this one.

```
function animate(url, callback, reverse, index) {
    var items = url.split('.'),
        length = 0;
    if (typeof index === 'undefined') { index = reverse ? items.length - 1 : 0; }
    if (index >= items.length || index < 0) {
        callback();
    } else {
        length = url.indexOf(items[index]) + items[index].length;
        console.log(url.length, items[index], url.slice(0, length));
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            animate(url, callback, reverse, reverse ? index - 1 : index + 1);
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

running it i got this log:

```
17 "ted" "sally.charlie.ted"
17 "charlie" "sally.charlie"
17 "sally" "sally"
18 "tina" "tina"
18 "heather" "tina.heather"
18 "david" "tina.heather.david"
```

Comment: amazing, and shorter! this was bugging me for 3 hours. you've made my day, thanks!

Comment: indexOf was the function I was missing to make this easier, very useful

Comment: I've updated my fiddle to reflect your changes and change the logic around the if statement so it made more sense: http://jsfiddle.net/kmturley/oco5uxrn/3/